# SignalR ServerSentEvents behaves abnormally with ARR

Tags: signalr, server-sent-events, arr

In my application everything with SignalR was fine until i configured ARR, after that ServerSentEvents protocol was not getting connected and displays error of timeout, I google for it than I found a solution to set "response buffer threshold" to 0 in ARR.

After that ServerSentEvents get connected but after timeout 2 to 3 time, I tried a lot to figure it out but not able to understand why its not getting connected for the very first time and my other issue is that when server push a message to client it takes about 3 to 5 seconds to receive by the client but when i push more messages in same time from server then client receives all messages immediately but it takes 3 to 5 seconds again for the last message, I don't know if signalr having some sort of queuing mechanism for serversentevent or something like that,

All these issues are after configuring of ARR

So, any help will be appreciable

Comment: It might be useful to say which browsers you are testing in (and if the behaviour is identical in all of them).

Comment: Yes it's same for every browser

Comment: Which browsers, exactly? E.g. if it works the same for IE10 as the latest Firefox then you are not using SSE, as IE still does not support it. So with IE, `signalr` will be emulating with one of the Comet fallbacks. Maybe it is doing the emulation for other browsers too? (Sorry, I am not familiar with signalr or arr, so cannot help any further.)

Comment: I tested this for firefox and chrome both having same issues, i didn't tried for IE

Comment: For Firefox, if you use the Network tab of Firebug, you'll be able to see the SSE connection being made; it might give you some insight into what the problem is.